# A compactly supported continuous function on an open subset of $\mathbb R^n$ is Riemann integrable. What is the relevance of openness in the proof?

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, integration, measure-theory, differential-geometry

My book is An Introduction to Manifolds by Loring W. Tu. A proposition in Subsection 23.2 ([Proposition 23.4](https://i.stack.imgur.com/g5UyH.png)) is

> If a continuous function $f: U \to \mathbb R$ defined on an open subset $U$ of $\mathbb R^n$ has compact support, then $f$ is Riemann integrable on $U$.

What is the relevance of openness of $U$, specifically the proof given?

- One might argue it's about smooth extensions of $f$ like in [Proposition 13.2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BS3fL.png) for $M = \mathbb R^n$ (which relies on openness of $U$ specifically through [Exercise 13.1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GqvAT.png) although the openness of $U$ is not explicitly used based on the [solution provided](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PxCWo.png), but assuming I understand right, I think I know where the openness of $U$).
- But I think the $\tilde{f}$ is not the one in [Proposition 13.2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BS3fL.png) but rather the one in [Subsection 23.1 (see (1) below)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NE8Xz.png), which does not make use of any bumps and has no claims of smoothness or continuity, though the $\tilde{f}$ in [Proposition 23.4](https://i.stack.imgur.com/g5UyH.png) is of course proven continuous on $\mathbb R^n$ assuming $f$ is continuous on $U$, open in $\mathbb R^n$ in the same way that the $\tilde{f}$ in [Proposition 13.2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BS3fL.png) is proven smooth on $M$ assuming $f$ is smooth on $U$, open in $M$.

  - Part of why I think so is that it says in the proof that $\tilde{f}$ agrees with $f$ on $U$, but that's not even what the $\tilde{f}$ of Proposition 13.2 does: $\tilde{f}$ agrees with $f$ on an equal or a smaller neighborhood: This is not only explicit in [Proposition 13.2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BS3fL.png) but also emphasized in a [remark](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6srrH.png) just before [Proposition 13.2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BS3fL.png).
- Additionally, I think $\tilde{f}$ is meant to be an extension not of $f$ but rather of $f|_{\text{supp} f}$. I ask about this [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3203211/if-a-continuous-function-f-u-to-mathbb-r-u-open-has-compact-support-th). Perhaps this should be resolved first.
- One thing I have in mind about how $U$'s openness is relevant is some kind of rule like $f$ Riemann integrable on $U$ if $f$ is Riemann integrable on $\text{supp} f (\subseteq U)$.
- Another thing I had in mind is something like $\overline \int_U f = \overline \int_U f 1_{\text{supp} f} = \overline \int_{\text{supp} f} f$ and $\underline \int_U f = \underline \int_U f 1_{\text{supp} f} = \underline \int_{\text{supp} f} f$ by the overline and underline versions of [Remark 10.7(i) in another book From Calculus to Cohomology by Ib Madsen and Jørgen Tornehave](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FBV7L.png) because $U$ is a manifold, because $U$ is open and because $\mathbb R^n$ is manifold...but I think this is overthinking not because this is from another book but because this uses geometry for an elementary analysis proposition.

---

Update: I think I know it now:

1. My mistake in [Method 1](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3203211/if-a-continuous-function-f-u-to-mathbb-r-u-open-has-compact-support-th) is deducing $\tilde{g}$ continuous at $x \in \text{supp} f$ simply because $g$ is continuous at $x$. This is not necessarily true, but $\tilde{f}$ continuous at $x \in U$ from $f$'s continuity at $x$ BECAUSE $U$ is open.
2. However, we must also prove $\tilde{f}$ and $\tilde{g}$ are identical. Much like with [$T_eG$ and $L(G)$ in Lie algebras](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VAk2o.png), each hand washes the other: $\tilde{g}$ is an extension from a bounded but closed set and therefore while we can use Lebesgue, we can't deduce continuity. $\tilde{f}$ is an extension from an open set but possibly unbounded set and therefore while we can't use Lebesgue, we can deduce continuity.
3. Therefore, the proof of [Proposition 23.4](https://i.stack.imgur.com/g5UyH.png) is as follows:

   - For continuous $f: U \to \mathbb R$ with $U$ open in $\mathbb R^n$ and with compact support, there exists a extension of $f$ by zero $\tilde{f}: \mathbb R^n \to \mathbb R$, i.e. $\tilde{f}(x) = f(x) \cdot 1_U(x) + 0 \cdot 1_{U^c}(x)$ which is a continuous extension because $f$ is continuous AND because $U$ is open (and compact support is not used here, I think). Lebesgue's theorem does not directly apply here because $U$ is not given to be bounded.
   - For $g=f|_{\text{supp} f}$, the restriction of $f$ to its support, we have $\tilde{g}: \mathbb R^n \to \mathbb R$, $\tilde{g}(x) = g(x) \cdot 1_{\text{supp} f}(x) + 0 \cdot 1_{(\text{supp} f)^c}(x))$, the extension of $g$ by zero.
   - **Underemphasized in my opinion**: Observe $\tilde{g}$ is not only an extension from a bounded set **but also identical** to $\tilde{f}$.
   - In [Lebesgue's theorem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/g5UyH.png) choose the bounded set $A = \text{supp} f$, and the bounded function to be $g$ which we can do because $\text{supp} f$ is bounded because $f$ has compact support and say that $\tilde{g}$ is continuous, not because $\tilde{g}$ is an extension of a continuous function, namely $g$, but because $\tilde{g}$ is identical to a continuous function, namely $\tilde{f}$.
   - Oh, there's something missing here: We have shown $g=f|_{\text{supp} f}$ is Riemann integrable. How exactly do we get that the original $f$ is Riemann integrable? Intuitively, I guess this has something to do with $(\text{supp} f)^c \subseteq \{f=0\}$. At this point, I think geometry's/topology's role is done, and analysis has to take over. I guess $$\int_U f = \int_{\text{supp} f} f + \int_{U \cap (\text{supp} f)^c} f = \int_{\text{supp} f} f + 0 = \int_{\text{supp} f} f = \int_{U} f|_{\text{supp} f},$$ but that relies on $\int_U f$ being well-defined in the first place. Hence I suspect some equivalent definition of Riemann integrability or at least some property of Riemann integrability is that $f$ is Riemann integrable if $f_{\text{supp} f}$ is Riemann integrable.

---

(1) Actually, the [solution](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PxCWo.png) to [Exercise 13.1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GqvAT.png) makes use of something called "extended by zero", but I don't think that's defined until [Section 23](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NE8Xz.png).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. In the proof of Prop. 23.4, by the extended function, I mean the extension by zero defined in Section 23.1.  If $U$ is not open, the extended function $\overline{f}$ need not be continuous at a boundary point of $U$.  For example, if $U$ is the closed interval $[-1,1]$ in the real line and $f(x) = x^2$ for $x$ in $U$, then $\overline{f}$ agrees with $f$ on $U$, but $\overline{f}$ is not continuous at $+1$ or $-1$.

Since $U$ is open in $\mathbb{R}^n$, an open subset of $U$ is also an open subset of $\mathbb{R}^n$.  Let $p$ be a point of $U$.  Then $\overline{f}$ agrees with $f$ on an open neighborhood of $p$ in $\mathbb{R}^n$, so $\overline{f}$ is continuous at $p$.

2. To Apply Lebesgue's theorem, which requires the domain of $f$ to be bounded, let $K$ be the support of $f$, a bounded set. Note that $\overline{f}$ is also the zero extension of the restriction of $f$ to $K$.  Since $\overline{f}$ is continuous, $f$ is Riemann integrable on $K$.  This implies that $f$ is Riemann integrable on $U$, since $f$ is zero on $U - K$.

Comment: This was my main concern: $\overline{f}$ is the zero extension of both $f$ and $g$! Thanks Prof. Tu!

Answer (score 1):

Because on ugly enough domains, even constant functions are non-integrable (see, for instance, [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3202915/finding-a-subset-d-such-that-the-restriction-of-f-to-d-is-not-riemann-inte). Assuming $U$ to be open stops that from happening.

Comment: Oh my mistake. I mean what specifically the [given proof](https://i.stack.imgur.com/g5UyH.png) uses openness of $U$? Edited question.

Comment: Oh, I think I know. It's implicit in the part that says "$\tilde{f}$ agrees with $f$ on $U$" right? Please see my [other question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3203211/if-a-continuous-function-f-u-to-mathbb-r-u-open-has-compact-support-th).

Comment: @SeleneAuckland I think it's the part where they claim one can extend $f$ continuously by letting it be $0$ everywhere outside $U$. That extension (is that what $\tilde f$ is?) won't be continuous in general, but assuming that $U$ is open ensures that the support of $f$ is "separate" from the complement of $U$.

Comment: Oh yeah I was actually about retract the comment. Anyway, yeah that's indeed what $\tilde{f}$ is, and I know (well at least I think I know) that $\tilde{f}$ isn't necessarily continuous for an arbitrary continuous $f$. Now, the part with the "$\tilde{f}$ agrees with $f$ on $U$" is Case 1 of proving that $\tilde{f}$ is continuous, so you're referring to Case 2? Well, I know that $\text{supp} f \subseteq U$ because $U$ is the domain of $f$ and thus $\text{supp} f \cap U^c = \emptyset$, but this is because of $A \subseteq B \iff A \cap B^c = \emptyset$ and not openness?

Comment: Or by "separate" do you mean a different thing from "disjoint" ?

Comment: Wait I think you're indeed referring to case 1 like this: For $f$ continuous at $x$, we have that for each neighborhood $V_{f(x)}$ of $f(x)$ in $\mathbb R$, there exists a neighborhood $W_x$ of $x$ in $U$ such that $f(W_x) \subseteq V_{f(x)}$. Now for $\tilde f$ to be continuous at $x$, we must find, for each neighborhood $Y_{\tilde f(x)} = Y_{f(x)}$ of $\tilde f(x) = f(x)$ in $\mathbb R$, some neighborhood $N_x$ of $x$ in $\mathbb R$ such that $f(W_x) \subseteq V_{f(x)}$. Because $U$ is open in $\mathbb R^n$, $W_x$ is too, and this allows us to choose $N_x = W_x$. Is that right?

Comment: I updated my question with a proof. Is it right please?