# Is a coordinate chart positively oriented if and only if the differential of the coordinate map is orientation-preserving?

Tags: linear-algebra, general-topology, multivariable-calculus, differential-geometry, vector-spaces

My book is From Calculus to Cohomology by Ib Madsen and Jørgen Tornehave.

This is the definition of [local index](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3218005/what-is-local-index-when-p-is-a-regular-value-but-not-in-the-image-of-f), Theorem 11.9 and the beginning of the proof of Theorem 11.9, which refers to [Lemma 11.8](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8Oqxp.png).

[image]

In the beginning of the proof, I think it is claimed that $f|_{V_{q_i}}$ is positively oriented if and only if $D_qf$ is orientation-preserving.

1. Do I understand right?
2. If not, then what is meant? If so, then is the following proof correct?

   - 2.1 In the first place, $(V_{q_i},f_{V_{q_i}})$ is a coordinate chart about $q_i$ in $N$, by [Proposition 6.11](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EdyG4.png) in An Introduction to Manifolds by Loring W. Tu, and therefore it makes sense to talk about whether or not $f|_{V_{q_i}}$ is positively oriented since I guess "positively oriented" is for coordinate maps and not arbitrary diffeomorphisms of manifolds...unless "positively oriented" actually means orientation-preserving, so the use of the adjective "positively oriented" for charts actually comes from the use of "positively oriented" for arbitrary diffeomorphisms of manifolds.

     - Update: It's not a chart, as pointed out in answer. I forgot that I had actually realized that earlier.
   - 2.2 $f|_{V_{q_i}}$ is positively oriented if and only if $D_q(f|_{V_{q_i}})$ is orientation-preserving.

     - I'm not too sure about what the definition of a positively oriented chart is (see [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3210811/what-might-be-the-definition-of-a-positively-oriented-chart-in-from-calculus-to?noredirect=1&lq=1) and [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3190944/is-the-differential-at-a-regular-point-a-vector-space-isomorphism-of-tangent-sp)), but what I'm hoping is that whatever the definition is, (2.2) is an equivalent definition.
   - 2.3 $D_q(f|_{V_{q_i}})$ and $D_q(f)$ are identical by chain rule and by the fact that differential of inclusion from an open subset is still inclusion
   - 2.3 Therefore, by (2.2) and (2.3), $f|_{V_{q_i}}$ is positively oriented if and only if $D_qf$ is orientation-preserving.
   - 2.4 Remark: I think we don't assume connectedness here.
3. Do we have that $f|_{V_{q_i}}$ is negatively oriented if and only if $D_qf$ is orientation-reversing even if $U$ isn't connected?

---

Some context:

- [Is the differential at a regular point, a vector space isomorphism of tangent spaces, also a diffeomorphism of tangent spaces as manifolds?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3190944/is-the-differential-at-a-regular-point-a-vector-space-isomorphism-of-tangent-sp)
- [What might be the definition of a positively oriented chart in From Calculus to Cohomology?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3210811/what-might-be-the-definition-of-a-positively-oriented-chart-in-from-calculus-to)
- [Why do connected oriented manifolds have compactly supported forms with integral one but with support contained in a given open proper subset?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3207958/why-is-there-a-form-with-compact-support-on-a-connected-oriented-manifold-with-i)

Answer (score 2):

If you have a diffeomorphism $\phi : A \to B$ between oriented manifolds, then all $D_q\phi : T_qA  \to T_{\phi(q)}B$ are isomorphisms of oriented vector spaces. This gives you a function $\sigma_\phi : A \to \{+1, -1 \}$ defined by $\sigma_\phi(q) = +1$ iff  $D_q\phi$ is orientation preserving. This function is locally constant, hence constant on each connected component $C$ of $A$. This means that $\phi \mid_C$ is either orientation preserving or orientation reversing. But note that on each connected component $\sigma_\phi$ may take an individual value. In other words, for a non-connected $A$ you may have the situation that $\phi$ is neiter orientation preserving nor orientation reversing.

This is the reason why $U$ is assumed to be connected. In that case you can moreover say that $f \mid_{V_i}$ is orientation preserving iff $D_qf$ is orientation preserving.

For your point 3. the answer is yes only for connected $U$.

Comment: Is (2.4) wrong? My understanding is as follows 2.4.a. for connected $U$, $f|_{V_{q_i}}$ must be either positively or negatively oriented and $D_q(f|_{V_{q_i}})$ must be either orientation-preserving or orientation-reversing, and 2.4.b. that $f|_{V_{q_i}}$ is positively (negatively) oriented if and only if $D_q(f|_{V_{q_i}})$ is orientation-preserving (orientation-reversing).

Comment: 2.4.c. For disconnected $U$, $f|_{V_{q_i}}$ may be neither positively or negatively oriented. 2.4.d. $D_q(f|_{V_{q_i}})$ may be neither orientation-preserving or orientation-reversing. 2.4.e. However, whenever, which may be never, we have that $f|_{V_{q_i}}$ is positively (negatively) oriented, we have that $D_q(f|_{V_{q_i}})$ must be orientation-preserving (orientation-reversing), and the converse is true.

Comment: For (3) to clarify, my understanding (this is kind of similar to (2.4.a-e) in comments above) is that for disconnected $U$, we have that "$f_{V_{q_i}}$ is not positively oriented" is not equivalent to saying that "$f_{V_{q_i}}$ is negatively oriented", so what is wrong with saying that whenever, which may be never, $f_{V_{q_i}}$ is negatively oriented, we have that $D_q(f|_{V_{q_i}})$ is orientation-reversing, or conversely?

Comment: Although I do not know the book by Madsen and Tornehave, it is obvious  that $f \mid_{V_k} : V_k \to U$ is not a chart on $N$ since $U \subset M$, but a diffeomorphism between manifolds (which are open subsets of $N, M$). Hence the wording "$f \mid_{V_k}$ is positively (negatively) oriented" must be a synonym for "$f \mid_{V_k}$ is orientation preserving (reversing)". This is a reasonable generalization of being "positively (negatively) oriented" from charts on oriented manifolds to diffeomorphisms between oriented manifolds.

Comment: A single $D_q(f \mid_{V_k})$ is always orientation-preserving or orientation-reversing, but only for connected $U$ one can conclude that the whole diffeomorphism $f \mid_{V_k}$ is orientation-preserving or orientation-reversing.

Comment: But be aware that notation is frequently not standardized in the literature. So you have to be careful when reading different books at the same time.