# Is $\int_X d(F^{*}\omega) = 0$ because of a corollary of Stokes' Theorem?

Tags: calculus, integration, multivariable-calculus, differential-geometry, stokes-theorem

My book is From Calculus to Cohomology by Ib Madsen and Jørgen Tornehave.

The last part of [Proposition 11.11](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nnzF1.png) goes $$\int_X d(F^{*}\omega) = \int_X F^{*}(d\omega) = 0$$

Can we just skip commutativity of pullback and exterior derivative and directly say that $\int_X d(F^{*}\omega) = 0$ by [Corollary 10.9](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nzULN.png) of [Stokes' Theorem (Theorem 10.8)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZqpY9.png)?

If we cannot skip, then why is it that $\int_X F^{*}(d\omega) = 0$?

By the way, if anyone wants to know the definition of domain with smooth boundary: I think this is the book's term for a subset, of a manifold, that is manifold with boundary. See here: [Why is there a form with compact support on a connected oriented manifold with integral one but with support contained in a given open proper subset?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3207958/why-is-there-a-form-with-compact-support-on-a-connected-oriented-manifold-with-i)

---

I realized my error: $X$ is not a manifold (without boundary)! We'll have to use commutativity and the fact that for any smooth $n$-dimensional manifold (without boundary) $M$, $\Omega^nM = Z^nM$, as pointed out below.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The point is that $\omega$ is an $n$-form on an $n$-dimensional manifold, so $d\omega = 0$. (The only $(n+1)$-form on an $n$-dimensional manifold is $0$.) On the other hand, $F^*\omega$ is an $n$-form on an $(n+1)$-dimensional manifold, so, as such, its exterior derivative would not necessarily have to be $0$.

Comment: I actually make the specific mistake of assuming that $X$ is a manifold (without boundary) right? (See edit) Thanks!

Comment: Of course, the essential ingredient is that $X$ is a domain with boundary and the boundary has the same dimension as $M$.

Comment: Why isn't it that $\dim(\partial X)=\dim(X)-1=\dim(M)-1$?

Comment: Because $X$ started out $(n+1)$-dimensional?